# Get all connected nodes in Titan

Tags: gremlin, titan

I want to get all connected nodes from a single node in titan.
For example if I have a graph like 
[image]

If I start from node m1 I want to get all nodes m3, m2 and m4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

`graph.traversal().V(m3).repeat(both()).until(cyclicPath()).both().dedup()`

which would contain the m3 vertex, but you could either `filter` it in the traversal or afterward where ever you're consuming the result.